# Contact Form 7 Selectable Recipients with Pipe - include CC and BCC

Tags: wordpress, pipe, contact-form-7, cc, bcc

Using WordPress Contact Form 7 and the Selectable Recipient with Pipes, I want to include CC and/or BCC along with the selection. This code doesn't work, but should illustrate my intent.

`[select* email-recipient "Sales|salesA@yourdomain.com, CC:salesB@domain.com" "Inquiry|infoA@domain.com, BCC:infoB@domain.com"]`

How can I do this?

Comment: Add Cc &Bcc into your Aditional header, and add [email-recipient] into mail To tag

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Note: the CC and BCC addresses are *Different* for each of the original recipients. I want *Conditional* CC and BCC based on the recipient.

Comment: any help please?